# Documents.Close makes Word visible

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have been trying a workaround for this, for quite a long time, but haven't found one yet.
On calling `Documents.Close()`, Word, which was opened with `visible = false`, becomes visible.

This is my close statement (document is already saved so no need to save again):

```
    WordApp.Documents.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges,
    Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call `WordApp.Quit()`.

Office apps still follow the MDI approach: You run 1 App and in that app you can open 1 or more documents.

It's easy to lose track of that App in the background as we usually only open one document. But there are two levels of Close here.

Answer (score 1):

You could also explicitly set `WordApp.Visible = false` immediately after the operation; this might cause a brief flash, but should set the application back to invisible.

To avoid the brief flash of visibility, sometimes using the `WordApp.ScreenUpdating` property as well can help. Set it to false before attempting the `Documents.Close()` call, then reset to true after that's complete.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution (calling WordApp.Quit()) was not a viable option for me. I tried setting

```
WordApp.ScreenUpdating = false
```

immediately prior to calling Documents.Close() and that did not help either - I still got the screen flash.

I then tried setting

```
WordApp.ActiveWindow.Visible = false
```

immediately after opening the document. That did not make any difference either.

Finally I tried setting

```
WordApp.ActiveWindow.Top = -5000
```

(so as to move the window display well out of the visible desktop area in my monitor setup - if you have an unusual (giant!) monitor setup that might not work for you, adjust accordingly) and that solved the problem - no more flashing.

An annoying hack, but worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

None of above comments work for me. I tried with:

`WordApp.ActiveWindow.Top = -5000`

But my program terminates with "active window is maximized" exception.

I ultimately resolved it by following call before invoke `Document.Close()`:

`m_word.ActiveWindow.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;`

It's a perfect solution for me. Hope it would work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ActiveDocument.Close() method will not show the window.
`WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(saveChanges: false);`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I finally realized that for me it was the AutoOpen macro that was the problem. Every time a Word document was opened, AutoOpen would make the `ActiveDocument.Visible = False`, run some changes (like opening the style pane), then turn `ActiveDocument.Visible = True` at the end.

This final line in AutoOpen is what caused every document to briefly flash on the screen. Removing both `ActiveDocument.Visible = False` and `ActiveDocument.Visible = True` from the AutoOpen macro solved the issue.